# What is the canonical form based on sinus of the autoinduced EMF in a coil

Tags: ac, coil, emf

I am stuck with this exercise as I can't really find the expressions I need in order to solve this. Please help me & guide me theoretically, so I can finish this.

Deduce the canonical form based on sinus of the autoinduced EMF in a coil knowing that: L = 3 [mH] ( I think it's called inductance in English or inductivity ) and that the coil is traveled by a current given like this:
i1 = 3√2 sin(314t + pi/3) [A].

So basically what I got out so far is this:

I1 ( complex number ) = 3 [A] and γ1 = pi/3 [rad]

I also found somewhere this formula regarding the EMF: e = -L * (ΔI/Δt) but I have no idea if it's the right one to use and exactly how and why to use it to get my desired result. Any ideas guys?

Comment: find the impedance and and there you go... or use the differential equation

Comment: Thank you for your help but this is exactly what I don't get. My course doesn't really specify at this point either of the things you mentioned and I'm really a beginner here. Please help me by sharing the exact formula I should use, and I will try to understand it theoretically after I have it & find it online. It's hard being a beginner with poor documentation hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I also found somewhere this formula regarding the EMF

Yes that's the correct formula and for a powered inductor the back (induced) emf it is Faraday's / Lenz's law: -

$$V = -L\dfrac{di}{dt}$$

So the induced (or back) emf is the mathematical differential of the current you have listed. This means the back emf is advanced by 90 degrees (then inverted by the minus sign) for a sinus driven coil thus your current of phase angle \$\pi/3\$ (or 60 degrees) is advanced to 150 degrees by the differentiation then inverted to -30 degrees by the minus sign.

Or just advance +60 degrees to -30.

Comment: Just to be sure, the final result should be this? e = 9√2 * 1/1000 * sin(-314t-pi/6) [H*A]

Comment: you have a minus sign in front of the 314t that shouldn't be there (unless you are a time traveller LOL).

Comment: Hahaha, indeed, my mistake. Thank you again for your help!